# problems with circular movement calculations

Tags: c++, graphics, geometry

**Question rescinded by original poster**

Hey so when running the following code my square is supposed to travel around in a circle, but there is some kind of issue with the function that calculates the x,y movement that should happen based on the velocity and angle of travel.

It succesfully travels around and around, but not in the right way. the 2nd and 4th quadrant are kind of inversed, and curving inwards towards the center of the circle rather than outward.

I can't figure out what the problem is... anyone wanna help?

```
#include<SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include<SFML/System.hpp>
#include<cmath>
#include<vector>
#    define M_PI 3.14159265358979323846 

sf::RenderWindow Window;

template<typename T> 
void CalculateMove(T Time, T Speed, T Angle, T& buffX, T& buffY)
{   //Make the degrees positive
    if(Angle<0) Angle= 360-Angle;
    //determine what quadrant of circle we're in
    unsigned int  Quadrant= 1;
    if(Angle>90)  Quadrant= 2;
    if(Angle>180) Quadrant= 3;
    if(Angle>270) Quadrant= 4;

    //anything above 90 would be impossible triangle
    Angle= (float)(Angle-(int)Angle)+(float)((int)Angle%90); 

    // calculates x and y based on angle and Hypotenuse.02433
    if((int)Angle!=0){
        buffX= sin(Angle / 180 * M_PI)/ (1.f/(Speed*Time));
        buffY= sin((180-Angle-90)/ 180 * M_PI)/ (1.f/(Speed*Time));}

    else{// Movement is a straight line on X or Y axis
        if(Quadrant==0 || Quadrant==2) buffX= Speed*Time;
        if(Quadrant==1 || Quadrant==4) buffY= Speed*Time;}

    //Quadrant Factor (positive or negative movement on the axis)
    switch(Quadrant){
    case 1: break;
    case 2: buffX=-buffX; break;
    case 3: buffX=-buffX; buffY=-buffY; break;
    case 4: buffY=-buffY; break;}
};

/////////////////////////////////////////   Mysprite    ////////////////////////////////
class mySprite : public sf::Sprite
{
private:
    float velocity;
    float angle;

public:
    // all the values needed by the base class sprite();
    mySprite(
        const sf::Image& Img, 
        const sf::Vector2f& Position = sf::Vector2f(0, 0), 
        const sf::Vector2f& Scale = sf::Vector2f(1, 1), 
        float Rotation = 0.f, 
        const float Angle= 0.f, 
        const float Velocity= 0.f, 
        const sf::Color& Col = sf::Color(255, 255, 255, 255)):
      Sprite(Img, Position, Scale, Rotation, Col){
        angle= Angle;
        velocity= Velocity;};

    float Velocity(){return velocity;};
    void SetVelocity(float newVelocity){velocity=newVelocity;};
    float Angle(){return angle;};
    void SetAngle(float newAngle){angle=(float)(newAngle-(int)newAngle)+(float)((int)newAngle%360);};

    void Update(){ 
        float frameTime= Window.GetFrameTime();
        float X=0,Y=0;
        CalculateMove(frameTime,velocity,angle,X,Y);
        Move(X,-Y);
    };

    void Accelerate(float PPS){velocity+=PPS;};
    void Turn(float degrees){
        float test= (float)((angle+degrees)- (int)(angle+degrees)); //TODO: Get rid of these test
        float test2=(float)((int)(angle+degrees)%360);
        float test3=test+test2;
        angle=(float)((angle+degrees)-(int)(angle+degrees))+(float)((int)(angle+degrees)%360);};

    void Reflect(float CollAngle){
        SetRotation(-GetRotation());
        angle=-angle;
        //TODO: factor in the collision angle
    };
};

int main()
{
    Window.Create(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "Pong! by Griffin Howlett");
    sf::Image img;
    img.Create(30,50,sf::Color(255,0,0));
    mySprite box(img, sf::Vector2f(400,200), sf::Vector2f(1,1), 0, 180, 200);
    Window.Display();

    for(;;){
        Window.Clear();
        box.Update();
        box.Turn(45.0*Window.GetFrameTime());
        Window.Draw(box);
        Window.Display();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I was wrong in assuming the triangle formed and used to calculate the movement required to get to the x, y coordinates would always automatically use the Y axis as the side opposite of the 'Angle', and istead the coordinates were backwards for Quadrant 2 and 4, Thanks for the other feedback though!

Here's the updated code:

```
if((int)Angle!=0){
        if(Quadrant==2 || Quadrant==4) Angle=90-Angle; //The unit circle triangle is flipped otherwise, causing x and y to be switched
        buffY= sin(Angle / 180 * M_PI)/ (1.f/(Speed*Time));  
        buffX= sin((180-Angle-90)/ 180 * M_PI)/ (1.f/(Speed*Time));}
```

by doing 90-Angle i'm switching the angles used to find the X, and Y side of the imaginary triangle....

Answer (score 4):

Your first mistake:

```
if(Angle<0) Angle= 360-Angle;
```

should be:

```
if(Angle<0) Angle= 360+Angle;
```

I'm not quite sure why you're going to the trouble of dividing the angle into quadrants. Do you think that the `sin` function is only defined for the range of 0 to 90 degrees?

Comment: so i can later make the x and y movement negative or postive based on the quadrant is

Comment: @Griffin, the sin (and cos) functions will provide negative numbers for the appropriate angles automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure all of the problems, but this line of code is wrong:

```
if(Angle<0) Angle= 360-Angle;
```

If `Angle < 0` then 360 - Angle will be > 360

you can also clean up the quadrant setting code, otherwise when the Angle is > 270, you do the assignment 4 times.

```
int Quadrant = 1;
if (Angle > 270)
{
    Qadrant = 4;
}
else if (Angle > 180)
{
    Quadrant = 3;
}
else if (Angle > 90)
{
    Quadrant = 2;
}
```

Comment: would cleaning up the quadrant setting code save all that much proccess? I was thinking going through the process of checking if angle is bigger than 90, 180 etc. would take just as long as asigning 4 times.

Comment: Its not a huge savings, but in your code you are doing both the assignment as well as the comparison, this cuts it down to just comparison and a single assignment and reduces the number of comparisons. In yours each comparison is done every time, whereas here the further compare's are only done if the previous was false. As far as speed, in a tight loop it would add up. A comparison is faster than an assignment, so reducing the assignments as well as the comparisons is going to save some time (may be negligable) and (to me) its cleaner to limit the assignments (especially when debugging)